# Store outputs of Lm performed on conditional dataframe subsets?

Tags: regression, dataset, subset

I am trying to store the regression's slopes of two variables recorded for different individuals through a season.

What I would like is the slope of the regression for each individual for each day (there are multiple values for each day).

My problem is that I don't have the same number of row for each day, or the same number of day for each individuals.

A solution would be to extract subset of my original dataframe, perform the regression and store the slope afterwards - but the original dataframe is large and I am convinced there is a more automatic way of doing this...

I have looked at tapply and ddply functions, tried to filter my data but I can't come up with something doing what I want in a limited number of steps. Creating subsets is also not very practical -  I guess some kind of loop could help, but my attempts in R have all fail so far...

Here is an extract of the original dataframe (366462 obs):

```
   Treatment ID DOY Tair Tleaf
1          1 11 144 9.73  9.57
2          1 11 144 9.88  9.50
3          1 11 144 9.76  9.48
4          1 11 145 9.58  9.37
5          1 12 144 9.54  9.37
6          1 12 145 9.58  9.37
7          1 12 146 9.61  9.33
8          1 12 147 9.54  9.28
9          2 23 146 9.51  9.24
10         2 23 147 9.49  9.31
```

And what I would like would be, basically :

```
  DOY Treatment ID     Slope
1  144         1 11 0.9785230
2  145         1 11 0.9852797
3  144         1 12 0.9903222
4  145         1 12 0.9811266
5  146         1 12 0.9641987
6  147         1 12 0.9738634
7  146         2 23 0.9784893
8  147         2 23 0.9691279
```

Any help would be very welcome !